# Lifecycle hooks question: Changing input type with a directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to write a directive, such that whenever `<input vType="year">` is written in the template, the directive automatically sets `<input type="number"`. However, it's not working, and the form variable ends up being a string (i.e. year: "2000", not year: 2000) I am wondering if it'm not using the right lifecycle hook.
Here is my directive:

```
@Directive({
selector: 'input[vType]',
  host: {
    '(input)': '$event'
  }
})
export class YearControl {
  @Input() vType?: null | "year"
  maxLength = 4
  constructor(private control: NgControl, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    this.elRef.nativeElement.type = 'number'
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('type', 'number');
    this.elRef.nativeElement.type = 'number'
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange() {
      // some other irrelevant logic
  }
}
```

My template:

```
                        <mat-form-field>
                          <mat-label>{{ "YEAR" | translate }}</mat-label>
                          <input matInput vType="year" formControlName="year">
                        </mat-form-field>
```

However, the type="number" is not set on the <input because the control "year" ends up being a string, not a number.

Comment: Is it any different if you do it in ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: Tried it, but not working either :(